# Python: 3D list, sum columns

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

Essentially, I want to sum items in parallel lists, like so:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [4, 3, 2, 1]] # list of lists (can be more than two)

 [5, 5, 5, 5]  # result
```

**But,** the catch is that there is one more dimension of lists, essentially making it '3D'. But I only want to sum the second items in the innermost pairs:

```
[[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]],
 [[1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1]]]  # add the numbers downward

 [[0, 5], [0, 5], [0, 5], [0, 5]]   # result
```

The first items in each pair can be left alone. For them, just copying the first row is fine.

---

Anyway, I can't come up with a good way of doing this. I've found this way:

```
l = [[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]],
     [[1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1]]] 

s = map(sum, zip(*[[j[1] for j in i] for i in l])) # to be summed
o = [i[0] for i in l[0]] # others

result = [[j for j in i] for i in zip(o, s)]
```

...but I can't bare it. If there is a nicer way, then I'll greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for all your brainwork!

P.S. Remember, there can by any number of lists in the list, not just 2!

Comment: Have you looked at numpy arrays and masks? I think the first part "My ultimate goal.." makes the question a little confusing. Maybe you should take that part out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iteration variable can be unpacked as follow:

```
>>> for x in [[1,2], [3,4]]: print(x)
... 
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
>>> for a,b in [[1,2], [3,4]]: print(a+b)
... 
3
7
>>> for [a,b] in [[1,2], [3,4]]: print(a+b)
... 
3
7
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
>>> xs = [[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]],
...       [[1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1]],
...       [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]]
>>> 
>>> [[x[0][0],sum(b for a,b in x)] for x in zip(*xs)]
[[0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9]]
```

Comment: I was about to post this answer :( But I didnt know about the unpacking. `print [[item[0][0], item[0][1] + item[1][1]] for item in zip(*Data)]`

Comment: A _readable_ one liner! Exactly what I was hoping for. I can apply this to many different things, thanks.

Comment: Hang on, sorry to find this out now, but that only manages TWO lists... I need one that can manage any number. I.e, `len(xs)` can be more than two.

Comment: `[[[a for a in x[0]][0], sum(b for a,b in x)] for x in zip(*xs)]` for actually copying the first row of digits, instead of just writing zeros.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `numpy`? It can also handle 3 dimensional arrays, and simply sum the desired slice using `np.sum` on `x[:,:,1]` through given axis (`0`) and in order to preserve the columns from first row zip them together (`x[0,:,0]`)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array( [[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]],
               [[1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1]]] )
zip( x[0,:,0], np.sum( x[:,:,1], axis=0 ) )
```